# Console error while using selenium under WSL2

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run the test code that has been shared in Selenium documentation, because I use WSL2, I'm running Firefox webdriver in headless mode;

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


options = Options() 
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

There is no error outputs on command line. However, the geckofile.log file outputs like this,

```
1602532495397   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:52679
1602532495400   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "-headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofiletLwjrV"
*** You are running in headless mode.
console.error: SearchCache: "_readCacheFile: Error reading cache file:" (new Error("", "(unknown module)"))
1602532496837   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 38037
1602532496906   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
JavaScript error: resource://gre/actors/AutoCompleteChild.jsm, line 235: Error: Invalid autocomplete selectedIndex
1602532499412   Marionette  INFO    Stopped listening on port 38037
1602534735902   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:42551
1602534735905   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "-headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofilecTeoz7"
*** You are running in headless mode.
console.error: SearchCache: "_readCacheFile: Error reading cache file:" (new Error("", "(unknown module)"))
1602534737300   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 38781
1602534737312   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
1602534739717   Marionette  INFO    Stopped listening on port 38781
```

How can I fix this problem and do Web Scraping under WSL2?